# gitignore everything but 1 file

Tags: git, github

I am having trouble with my gitignore file.

My directories look like this:

```
/root
    /.gitignore
    /README.md
    /embedded-programming-periode-3/
        /somefolder/
        /somefiles.txt
        /main.c
```

And I want to ignore everything except:
.gitignore, README.md and main.c

How would I go about this? I tried various things without success.

Answer (score 0):

> And I want to ignore everything except: `.gitignore`, `README.md` and `main.c`

A quick look at the documentation of [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) shows that it is as easy as:

```
# ignore everything
/*

# except .gitignore, README.md
!/.gitignore
!/README.md

# excepting main.c is a bit tricky:
# must except its parent directory ...
!/embedded-programming-periode-3/
# ... ignore everything in it ...
/embedded-programming-periode-3/*
# ... except for main.c
!/embedded-programming-periode-3/main.c
```

Comment: I am new to git, but if I run git status, it should show up as a new file, right? Because that is not the case.

Comment: What says `git status`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DyzH2a1P

Comment: Make sure the `.gitignore` file is in the same directory as `README.md` and `embedded-programming-periode-3`. From the output you put on pastebin.com it seems the `.gitignore` file is inside the `embedded-programming-periode-3` directory.

Comment: The .gitignore is in the root folder of the project, so in the same directory as README.md

Comment: I think it looks like that because there is a embedded-programming-periode-3 folder inside embedded-programming-periode-3. With the first one being the root of the project.

Comment: It looks like that because it is like that. You added or modified the `.gitignore` file inside the `embedded-programming-periode-3` and that's why it doesn't work as expected.