# Git don't ignore single file

Tags: git, gitignore

I have my folder directory such as

```
|- backup/
|  -> other_folder/
|  -> other_folder2/
|  -> initdb.d/
|    -> place_sql_files_here
```

And in my gitignore for the project I have

```
backup/*
!backup/initdb.d/place_sql_files_here
```

Yet it seems to still be ignoring the `place_sql_files_here` file.  How can I prevent this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+single+file

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44568924/4265352) on a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44568184/4265352). Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48613786/4265352) on another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48613701/4265352).

Comment: @axiac neither of those worked, I saw both of those before I posted.  But I fixed it so I will close anyway.